# iptables repeated entry, what is the logic behind it?

Tags: linux, iptables, loopback

I bumped into these iptables entries for a specific scenario I needed to replicate!

iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP

iptables -P FORWARD DROP

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3389 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

And I cannot understand why this command below is repeated at the beginning and at the end?

iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

I know it is meant to accept the traffic destined for the localhost but I can't figure out the logic behind having it at the beginning of the list and again at the end before the implict drop all rule for the default chain! I thought having it at the beginning only is enough!

Thanks

Comment: The repeated rule at the end won't matter / ever be a match. It only causes an extra test on traffics that haven't been accepted by other rules before they are dropped due to the chain policy.

Comment: By the way, instead of repeating `-m state --state NEW` in all the "port" rules, you might want to simply have an early drop rule for traffics with the state `INVALID`.